# Terraform ec2 instances + EBS issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Having a few issues with counts in Terraform, wondering if anyone could advise. I have a set of three instances, with EBS volumes mounted to them in one of my modules. Please see code excerpt below:

```
  resource "aws_instance" "xxxx" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)}"

  ami                    = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${module.xxxx-sg.this_security_group_id}"]
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
  subnet_id              = "${element(module.vpc.xxxx_subnets, count.index)}"
  user_data              = "${module.xxxx-userdata.template_file}"

  tags {
    Name              = "${local.xxxx_name}"
  }

  root_block_device = [
    {
      volume_size           = 20
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      delete_on_termination = true
    },
  ]
}
```

This is paired with the following code to create and attach EBS volumes:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "xxxx-ebs" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)}"

  availability_zone = "${element(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names, count.index)}"
  size              = 100
  type              = "gp2"

  tags {
    Name = "${local.xxxx_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "xxxx-ebs-attachment" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)}"
  device_name = "/dev/sdg"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.xxxx-ebs.*.id[count.index]}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.xxxx.*.id[count.index]}"
}
```

So the syntax used above (aws_ebs_volume.xxxx-ebs.*.id[count.index]) was originally using the element() function in Terraform, but I was having issues whereby when one instance was terminated/edited...Terraform would attempt to reattach all EBS' to all instances, not just the one that had been changed. I amended and am currently using the syntax above and it has been working fine for the last few weeks, until a Terraform run this morning threw the following issues.

To give you a current view of the state, two of the xxxx instances have been terminated, so i'd expect it to recreate these two instances and reattach the existing EBS volumes. Error below

```
* module.prod-env0.aws_volume_attachment.xxxx-ebs-attachment: 2 error(s) occurred:

* module.prod-env0.aws_volume_attachment.xxxx-ebs-attachment[1]: index 1 out of range for list aws_instance.xxxx.*.id (max 1) in:
   ${aws_instance.xxxx.*.id[count.index]}

* module.prod-env0.aws_volume_attachment.xxxx-ebs-attachment[2]: index 2 out of range for list aws_instance.xxxx.*.id (max 1) in:
   ${aws_instance.xxxx.*.id[count.index]}
```

I'd be interested to see how others are managing their EBS volumes.

Comment: if the attachments are being made before the new instances are created you could try adding an explicit depends_on to the attachment resource

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. You should do

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "xxxx-ebs-attachment" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)}"
  device_name = "/dev/sdg"
  volume_id   = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.xxxx-ebs.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.xxxx.*.id, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: Hi Koe, thanks for this. I did actually have it set up as you mentioned however I was hitting another error. If one of the three instances was ever updated/terminated. Instead of just attempting to reattach the one EBS, it would attempt to reattach the EBS' on all three instances. This would obviously cause an error as you cannot reattach something that is already attached.